# How to delete the last page from grid/grDevices?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

Is there a method to delete the last page created with the `grid.newpage()` or revert the graphic device to the state before the last plot was added?

Background:

I wrote a function that adds a layer (eg. `geom_label`) to an existing `ggplot` with location of data points based on the absolute plot dimensions (eg. inches/lines), rather than data range.

The procedure is: produce a plot, print it on the current device, measure the printed grobs and enhance the data frame to be plotted with relevant statistics (eg. origin of the coordinate system per panel, relative units per inch or per line), create the new plot with an additional layer with `aesthetics` computed with these new variables, print this final plot.

The main purpose was to have a tool that nicely aligns additional text/labels with summary statistics within the plotting area, even when facets or grouping variables are in use.

The issue is that an unnecessary page is produced with the plot I do not really use, except for making measurements, and I did not find any `grid` or `grDevices` method to delete the last printed page. Do you know of any such function?

There are some potential flawed workarounds: printing new `ggplot` object without calling `grid.newpage()` (but you no longer simply `print(plot)`), or plotting the first plot in a temporary device with same parameters as the target device (but it's not universal, and requires different approach per device; eg. solutions for .png and multipade .PDF will differ).

Answer (score 1):

Grid units already let you place objects at fixed positions in the panel,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ag <- grobTree(textGrob('+', x = unit(3,"cm"), y=unit(1,'npc') - unit(1,'in')))

qplot(1:10,1:10) +
  annotation_custom(ag)
```

Comment: This would be a nice solution if only allowed for different grobs per facet.

Comment: `egg::geom_custom` does